# angular error [$compile:ctreq]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tried to write a very simple tab component with angularJS and ionic. [ionic-tab](https://github.com/njleonzhang/ionic-tab)

If I use the component without Jquery, angular throws exception. If I include jquery to the project, the error just go away.

I think I haven't used anything on jquery, really don't why this issue occur.

Is there any one help to review my code? (git: [ionic-tab](https://github.com/njleonzhang/ionic-tab))

Here is the codepen to repro the issue, [codepen](http://codepen.io/leonz/pen/mPOBwo)

```
    Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ion-simple-tabset', required by directive 'ionSimpleTab', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/ctreq?p0=ion-simple-tabset&p1=ionSimpleTab
    at http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:13380:12
    at getControllers (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:21319:19)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:21466:33)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:20853:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:20728:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:20872:16)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:21489:18)
    at ngDirective.link (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:41190:5)
    at invokeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:21962:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js:21462:11) <ng-transclude>
```

Comment: codepen looks fine to me.. how to reproduce the issue in codepen?

Comment: It appears the `ionic-tab` module depends on jQuery.

Comment: @PankajParkar  remove jquery from html，the issue will reproduce